# como insertar datos de un array en una tabla

Tags: php, mysql, array

Hola buenas tardes tengo rato tratando de resolver un problema

me explico:

tengo un formulario que al enviar los datos los almaceno en un array asociativo para pasarlos en el constructor de la clase ya que son muchas variables y no quiero sobre cargar el constructor de tantas variables y tampoco quiero crear tantos atributos en la clase, el array tiene 37 variables con sus respectiva keys, la pregunta es: ¿Como guardo cada dato de ese array en cada columna de la tabla?
agradecería su valiosa ayuda
saludos

Comment: Si el array asociativo está clave=>valor, esa clave puede ser el nombre de la columna a la que va a insertar ese dato que sería su valor  'columna_precio'=>'2000', de esa manera usted generaría la consulta dinamicamente, primero recorre el array para sacar sus calves, estas claves irían dentro del `INSERT INTO tabla (.clave1, clave2)` y sus valores dentro de su `values (.valorDeClave1, valorDeClave2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siguiendo la idea del comentario, una implementación simple puede ser la siguiente

```
$parametros_post = array(
  'p1' => 'valor',
  'p2' => 'valor2'
);
//suponiendo una conexión de bd abierta
$campos = '';
$parametros = '';
$parametros_consulta = array();
foreach($parametros_post as $nombre_parametro => $valor_parametro) {
  //validar datos, etc.
  $campos .= "$nombre_parametro,";
  $parametros .= ":$nombre_parametro,";
  $parametros_consulta[":$nombre_parametro"] = $valor_parametro;
}

$campos = trim($campos, ',');
$parametros = trim($parametros, ',');

$insert = "INSERT INTO tabla($campos) VALUES($parametros)";

echo $insert;

//preparar instrucción y ejecutar pasando como parametro el array $parametros_post y la conexión
```

Comment: Gracias amigo me sirvió de mucho, saludos